# Error while using QGraphicsScene functions in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, scene

I'm getting errors when I run a qt project and I can't understand what is the reason

errors:

> 'class MainWindow' has no member named 'setSceneRect'   'class
>   MainWindow' has no member named 'setScene'  `mapToScene' was not
>   declared in this scope

the code:

mainwindow.cpp:

```
 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
QGridLayout * gridLayout = new QGridLayout(ui->centralWidget);
gridLayout->addWidget( new MainWindow() );

scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    this->setSceneRect(50, 50, 350, 350);
    this->setScene(scene);
 }

 void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
    double rad = 1;
    QPointF pt = mapToScene(e->pos());
    scene->addEllipse(pt.x()-rad, pt.y()-rad, rad*2.0, rad*2.0,
        QPen(), QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern));
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
QGraphicsScene * scene;
```

Comment: I don't suggest you to run this code, it will consume all your memory. You allocate memory for mainwindow inside mainwidow's constructor. You constructor calls another constructor which calls another abd another. You need totally rewrite your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all do not make an instance of `MainWindow` in it's constructor. I think instead of `gridLayout->addWidget( new MainWindow() );` you should add your view to the main window :

```
gridLayout->addWidget(view);
```

You should call `setSceneRect` on `QGraphicsScene` :

```
scene->setSceneRect(50, 50, 350, 350);
```

Also you should assign a scene to a `QGraphicsView` by calling `QGraphicsView::setScene` :

```
QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView(this) ;
view->setScene(scene);
```

`mapToScene` is a function of `QGraphicsView`. So you should have something like :

```
QPointF pt = view->mapToScene(e->pos());
```

Finally i should mention that you can have a custom class which inherits from `QGraphicsView` and implement `mousePressEvent` and other things related to scene and drawing there. Then you can have an instance of your custom class in your `MainWindow`.

Comment: Thank you your answer soved the first two errors, but i still have this error: `mapToScene' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Have you also used `mapToScene` in your code? I don't see any.

Comment: sorry, I've edited the post. It is in mousePressEvent function

Comment: `mapToScene` is a function of `QGraphicsView`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much now I don't have errors. But when I click run no window appears to me. Any way I will accept your answer it was very helpful.

Comment: @shahdewai You should not make an instance of `MainWindow` in it's constructor. See the first part of the answer.